# Store "templates" of children

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript so forgive me if the question comes around as dumb.

I know that `appendChild()` allows me to add a child element to an existing element. However, the problem is that I want to add an element which has an image on the left and a series of text boxes on the right **and** I need to add it over and over again on button click.

Adding simple elements like `p`, `a` , etc can be done by a single call to `appendChild()`, however for the above scenario, it will be a little messy.

Is there some way that I can define the custom element that I want to append and then just add it with a single call to `appendChild()`

Comment: Why not just make a function that does all the messy stuff, and call that repeatedly?

Comment: @forgivenson I thought about that :) I come from the `Android` realm. There, we can define the templates in XML and one call to add the children. So I was looking from that perspective :)

Comment: Keep a reference to it in a variable?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah ! Exactly ! And create new instances of it so that they can be added to the webpage :)

Comment: @LittleChild no, that's it, you keep a reference to the template, and then use it several times :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jQuery? If it is a really complicated template, you could use [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to ajax in an template and populate it with whatever you have to. You wouldn't need to dynamically create all of the elements using javascript, only populate it. This would would also allow you to change your template if need be very easily.

Comment: Can you post an example ? :)

Comment: Forgot about that, you would probably be looking for $.get(), as you want to continue appending them. Here is a [fiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/def6054/RsL8V/10/ of course it wont fully work because of security and im lazy. But basically the **templates/whatever.html** is what would be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode):

```
target.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));  // If you want to clone template 
                                               // with all its descendants

target.appendChild(template.cloneNode(false)); // If you want to clone template 
                                               // without its descendants
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this quite a bit. My code generally looks like this:

```
<div class="template" style="display: none;">stuff</div>
```

then:

```
$('.template').clone(true).removeClass('template').show().appendTo(someElement);
```

Since you're not using jQuery, have a look at the clone function here:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js

(search for "clone: function" to find it)

You can steal the relevant bits if you can't actually use jQuery itself.

Comment: DOM has a cloneNode function. Please do not suggest jQuery answers to non jQuery questions especially when they add no value on top of not using jQuery.

Comment: Why should OP want to add near 100KB to the page just to avoid `cloneNode`?

Comment: To be clear, I was not suggesting that the OP adds jQuery. I was showing a solution using it and letting the OP know where they could get more details should they wish to do so. For example, the OP's code could be running in an environment where cloneNode is not available.